# VBA Populate Column Range based on value in Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write a script to populate a range of cells based on an input value.

The input value represents the highest number in the range, the script counts up to this value in increments of 9.

Example: 
Input Value 42.
Resulting range, one value per cell in a column:

001-010

011-020

021-030

031-040

041-042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expected to provide what you have tried but this should get you started :

```
Sub inc()

Dim V1 As Integer: V1 = InputBox("Enter a value")
Dim a As Integer: a = 1
Dim b As Integer: b = 1

Cells.Clear

For i = 10 To Round(V1, 10) Step 10
    Cells(a, 1) = Format(b, "000") & "-" & Format(i, "000")
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 10
Next i

Cells(a, 1) = Format(b, "000") & "-" & Format(V1, "000")

End Sub
```

Be careful as it is clearing the active sheet. You might want to change that.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I honestly didn't know where to start.